# How to Make Up Comebacks when Somebody Calls You?

Tags: formality, conversation, greetings

I heard when I called somebody they answered "You" or "Yo" . .
Which one is correct? and what does it mean?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo) and [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yo).

Comment: It's not likely to be *You*, unless it was in response to something relevant you had said. The only possibility is *Yo!*,  complete with an exclamation mark. :)

Comment: The appropriate way, if you are over 40, is stand silently and stare at the caller and grin. Then distend your head slightly to left (to the right if your are left handed) like a puzzled puppy, and extend your right (left if you are left-handed) palm at waist height, inviting that person to come over to ack your ack with a friendly slap on your palm.

Answer (score 1):

They most likely answered "Yo." I use this myself.

It's a concise and snappy way of saying "Hello, I'm paying attention to you." It is also used to attract someone's attention – as in "Yo, buddy!"

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yo